# HttpClient utility class .Net Webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnet-httpclient

I'm relatively new to using HttpClient and API's but I've done some searching around and it seems that the general consensus even from microsoft docs is that HttpClient **should** be instantiated once. I have multiple places where I need to make calls to an API endpoint in my project so I made an HttpClient utility class that can be called.

```
    public static class HttpClientManager
    {
        private static HttpClient _httpClient;
        private static HttpClientHandler _handler;
        private static readonly string _apiBaseUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiUrl"];

        static HttpClientManager()
        {
            if (_handler == null) _handler = new HttpClientHandler
            {
                UseDefaultCredentials = true,
                PreAuthenticate = true,
                AllowAutoRedirect = true,
                ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Automatic
            };

            if (_httpClient == null) _httpClient = new HttpClient(_handler, false);
        }

        public static HttpClient GetHttpClient()
        {
            if(_httpClient.BaseAddress == null)
            {
                _httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(_apiBaseUrl);
            }
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            return _httpClient;
        }
    }
```

The general idea is that the static constructor initializes the http client and then I have a static method GetHttpClient that will set the address and headers and return the client back which other classes in my project can then make a call like so HttpClientManager.GetHttpClient().GetAsync(.....)....

In theory this should ensure that the client gets initialized once on the first call in the static constructor and should re-use it throughout the life of the application. Is this the proper way of doing something like this or are there better designs?

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Why do you even have the `GetHttpClient()` function when all it does could be done in the static constructor just once?

Comment: You need to read [You're using HttpClient wrong and it's destabilizing your software](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) and [You're (probably still) using HttpClient wrong and it is destabilizing your software](https://josef.codes/you-are-probably-still-using-httpclient-wrong-and-it-is-destabilizing-your-software/). I highly recommend [Flurl](https://flurl.dev/) instead.

Comment: @Ottarl  We have the exact same question about using HttpClient on a website on ASP.NET Web Forms, 4.8 framework.  Did you get any more answers?  A working solution?